# Unable to loging to wp-admin even with the correct credentials

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, wp-admin

I am unable to login to the wp-admin or wp-login with correct user credentials. It just shows the password is an incorrect error when I am literally copying and pasting the exact password from the database.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is for programming-specific questions. Question about WordPress administration, server configuration, etc. are off topic and are more suited to the [dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com). However, this question might not be on topic on that site either as it stands - without any information to help identify where the problem might be, any answers are just guesswork.

Comment: if you're copying the exact value in the database then it will definitely not work since it's the hashed version of your password. use the forgot password feature

Comment: It's not sending any password to resent link when I do forget password.